# Building a datagrid to show different tables depending on Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, query-string

So, I have a control with a datagrid in it and I was wondering if depending on the value I get back from the a Request.QueryString if I could set the table name to that (that is the value being sent) and then have it build the columns?

I have about 3 different tables, and they have different amounts of columns, and of course with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to access the QueryString collection to get the table name your passing in then just create a new datatable and set its name.

/*Create the table and name it*/

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.TableName = Request.QueryString["VariableName"].ToString();

/*add the columns*/

dt.Columns.Add(Request.QueryString["VariableName"].ToString(), typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(Request.QueryString["VariableName"].ToString(), typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(Request.QueryString["VariableName"].ToString(), typeof(String));

Enjoy!

Comment: DataTable is not registering as a predefined type. I'm assuming it's something to do with my web.config. grr.

Comment: ok, got that. But there doesn't seem to be a Name for dt.Name. Closest thing is Namespace.

Comment: Hi Justin - You are correct its "TableName" - I apologize for the typo.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how I actually bind the data from my DB to these new columns? I'm using MS SQL